# ¿Qué acepción de "comunicar" utiliza el DLE cuando dice "le comunica una aceleración"?

Tags: definiciones, dle, acepciones

La definición de la palabra *[newton](https://dle.rae.es/newton)* según el DLE es (**negritas** mías):

> 1. m. Fís. Unidad de fuerza del sistema internacional, equivalente a la fuerza que, aplicada a un cuerpo cuya masa es de 1 kilogramo, le **comunica** una aceleración de 1 metro por segundo cada segundo. (Símb. N).

Ese uso de la palabra *comunicar* me ha parecido extraño, así que he ido a la definición de *[comunicar](https://dle.rae.es/comunicar)* en el DLE. Sin embargo, no parece haber ninguna acepción que tenga este significado (algo así como "provocar un efecto"). Las únicas acepciones de *comunicar* que no se refieren a personas son:

> [...]
>
> 4. tr. Transmitir señales mediante un código común al emisor y al receptor.
> 5. tr. Establecer medios de acceso entre poblaciones o lugares. *El puente comunica los dos lados de la bahía.* U. t. c. prnl.
>
> [...]
>
> 7. tr. desus. comulgar.
> 8. intr. Dicho de un lugar: Permitir el acceso a otro. El portal comunica con la bodega. U. t. c. prnl.
> 9. intr. Dicho de un teléfono: Dar, al marcar un número, la señal indicadora de que la línea está ocupada por otra comunicación.
> 10. prnl. Dicho de cosas inanimadas: Tener correspondencia o paso con otras.
> 11. prnl. Extenderse, propagarse. El incendio se comunicó a las casas vecinas.

Las dos últimas son pronominales, por lo que no pueden ser.

¿Qué acepción de *comunicar*, si hay alguna, es la más adecuada en la frase "comunicar una aceleración a un objeto", usada por el mismo DLE en la definición de *newton*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semánticamente la más cercana sería la 11, pero como bien dices la entrada indica que es pronominal y en este caso el verbo es transitivo. De todos modos no es infrecuente que la definición no recoja todos los usos; *golpear*, por ejemplo, se muestra en el DLE como transitivo o instransitivo, pero también se usa como pronominal.

Este uso es muy habitual en el campo de la física. La frase "le comunica una aceleración", con el sentido de *transmitir*, [es casi un lugar común en el planteamiento de problemas](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22comunica+una+aceleraci%C3%B3n%22&lr=lang_es&tbs=lr:lang_1es&tbm=bks&tbas=0).